Error using add_ci() with tbl_svysummary(percent="row") in R
I am trying to generate a summary table using the tbl_svysummary() function from the gtsummary package, calculating row percentages and grouping by sex. After that, I want to add confidence intervals (CI) using the add_ci() function. However, I receive a warning that add_ci() does not work with percent="row", and the confidence intervals are applied to the columns instead of rows, as shown below:
How can I modify the code or configure tbl_svysummary() so that add_ci() works with row percentages (percent="row") and applies confidence intervals to the rows instead of columns? Is there any alternative solution or adjustment needed for this situation?
